# Plotly.NET configuration issue

Tags: f#, plotly.net

Problem running Plotly.NET on F# Interactive. (VS2019, FSharp Core 7.0.0, Plotly.NET 3.0.1, TargetFramework: net472)

```
#r C:\....\.nuget\packages\plotly.net\3.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Plotly.NET.dll"

open Plotly.NET
let xData = [0. .. 10.]
let yData = [0. .. 10.]
let myFirstChart = Chart.Point(xData,yData)
```

Gives an error: " `C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\unknown(1,1): error FS3216: type 'Plotly.NET.GenericChart+GenericChart' not found in assembly 'Plotly.NET, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=.......'. A possible cause may be a version incompatibility. You may need to explicitly reference the correct version of this assembly to allow all referenced components to use the correct version.`"

What should be correct configuration for environment to get that running?

---

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you mention "TargetFramework: net472". Also I'm puzzled by your mention of "FSharp Core 7.0.0", since F# interactive is going to be tied to some specific version of F#, for VS 2019 that won't be 7.0.

It's better to use the new syntax for referencing a nuget package from a script:

```
#r "nuget: Plotly.NET"
```

I tried your code in VS 2019 (referencing the nuget package as above) and still got a weird error. I then went to Tools | Options | F# Tools | F# interactive and changed the option "Use .NET Core Scripting" from false to true. I then reset the F# interactive session to make the change take effect, and tried your code again, and it worked.

```
> let myFirstChart = Chart.Point(xData,yData);;
Binding session to 'C:/Users/jimfo/.nuget/packages/plotly.net/3.0.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Plotly.NET.dll'...
Binding session to 'C:/Users/jimfo/.nuget/packages/dynamicobj/2.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/DynamicObj.dll'...
val myFirstChart: GenericChart.GenericChart =
  Chart
    (Plotly.NET.Trace2D, Plotly.NET.Layout, Plotly.NET.Config,
     Plotly.NET.DisplayOptions)
```

I didn't bother testing 32 bit vs 64 bit or seeing what happens in VS 2022.

I don't know what the errors are about, I have seen some strange errors lately given the mix of F# compiler versions, FSharp.Core versions, VS versions (think of all the patched versions), and sometimes you have to just fool around a bit until you get the right combination that works.

Comment: Many thanks you for answer! .NET environment is quite a mess for beginner. In my configuration, It's easier to download packages using Nuget Package Manager. I cleaned all Nuget cache and downloaded packages for FSharp.Core 5.0 (right, as it is on VS 2019), referenced to local-packages folder and now I can see Plotly graph as a blank white browser window. Is it possible to use Plotly.NET in almost offline environment?

Comment: I think so; it's wrapping a Javascript library but I think it works fine locally.